# get a foreground image attached to the bottom right of my web page, on the footer element

Tags: html, css

Im writing a html page and i want an image to stick to the bottom of my footer on the right corner and stay there. 
this is what i want it to look Like:

I cant seem to get it right. it either doesnt stick completely to the bottom or completely to the right or it goes under the footer background image. Tried so many things im lost. Please help.
The parts with the dollar sign is also part of the image

Here is my CSS code:

```
.foreground
{
    float-right;
    position:static;
    bottom:0;
}
```

|----------------|
|....................|
|....................|
|    content     ......|
|................... |
|............------|
|...........|$$$$|
|---------|img..|
| footer  |div....|
| bg ....
 |$$$$|
|---------|$$$$|

Comment: Please give us some code...

Comment: `position:fixed; bottom:0; right:0; z-index:999999;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you want, here's a jsfiddle I knocked together: http://jsfiddle.net/78TB7/
`position: absolute` is your friend here.

Comment: Thanks soo much!! Appreciate it :D this worked! What i was missing was making the body element position to relative. Otherwise the image stayed in the middle of the page. Wonder why that is the case ??

Comment: Position absolute positions itself based on the next containing element with a relative, fixed or absolute position

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can do this through the following CSS:

```
.your_element{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:999;
}
```

But since you haven't provided any code, it would be hard to tell.

Comment: .foreground {
 float-right;
 position:static;
 bottom:0;
}
but it shows below the footer

Comment: I tired position fixed but it makes it stick to the bottom of the screen instead of the bottom of the page..

Comment: Yes, fixed is designed to do that. To avoid it "sticking," try using the code above, but replace `fixed` with `absolute`

Comment: Thanks!! This works perfect nw :) i was using the wrong position in my containing element!!

Comment: Glad to hear! Can you mark this answer as the solution by clicking the green check to the left?

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
da1
{

position:absolute;
right:0px;
bottom:0px;
z-index:-1;
}
```

try this what it shows?
You didn't provide any code, so hard to say..

Comment: Thanks!! :) i was using the wrong position in my containing element!!

Comment: its ok,ur welcome..u can mark green at the left side...as the right answer if its helpful to u.